# Android: How to detect a Task Killer (e.g. Clean Master) with accessibility services?

Tags: android, task, accessibility, kill, detect

How can I programmatically tell whether **any** task killer (e.g. Clean Master) is installed and has accessibility privileges to force-stop other apps?

Example for task killers that can force stop apps:

- Clean Master
- Advanced Task Killer

**Note:** I do not want to specifically detect "Clean Master". I want to detect **ANY** task killer than can force stop my app.

[image: Accessibility privileges to Force Stop apps]